# Home remedy for coughing dog

Tags: dogs, health

My dog got infected with a cough and the soonest I can bring him to a vet is in 2 days.

- I know for certain that this is an infection but I don't know the exact bacteria / viruses that caused the infection.
- He is coughing and gagging and quite regularily coughing up white slime.
- He is eating and drinking as usual.
- He doesn't have a fever as far as I can tell.

What can I do to improve his symptoms until I can go the vet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the vet with my dog and he gave me the following information:

As mentioned by [motosubatsu](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/22095/12501), **coughing can be a symptom of very serious ailments**. If you're not sure why you dog coughs, you should get to the vet as soon as possible. (In my case I knew exactly where he got infected, so I was sure it wasn't something serious.)

- AVOID INFECTING OTHER DOGS! Don't go to crowded places and warn approaching people not to let their dog come into contact with yours. One touch nose to nose is enough to infect a dog.
- Let a veterinarian have a look at your dog to exclude that your dog has a serious medical problem.
- Keep the dog warm. Let him sleep in a warm place. If it's cold outside and you have a short-haired breed, use a dog coat when walking.
- Avoid strenuous activities. A walk through the woods is OK, but don't play fetch or let him run after you on a bicycle.
- Make sure he always has water nearby.
- Cooled tea like cistus or camomile with a dab of honey can help a dog as well as a human (meaning: not much but better than nothing). **Make sure the tea you want to feed is not harmful to dogs!**

Answer (score 2):

Wet coughing in dogs is potentially **very** serious, this really is a no mucking around get them to the vet ASAP thing.

I don't mean to scare you but causes of wet coughs go all the way up to Congestive Heart Failure!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but in this special case I'm absolutely sure that it's an infection (like a cold for humans) because I know exactly where he became infected. If he showed signs of fatigue or general weakness I would have brought him to the emergency vet immedietly.